# python urllib2.urlopen errno 61 (again?!?)

Tags: macos, python-2.7

Ok, I know this error has come up before, and yes, I'm using python 2.7.3 on mac osx 10.7.5 (also same error using mavericks), not the latest or best.  But (of course) it's legacy code -- and it worked yesterday, and it doesn't work today.

What changed?  Well, I did switch from RCN to Comcast as ISP provider, and also moved cities.  I don't see any previous posts about those specific changes, and I've tried everything I can think of, over many hours.

I can reproduce the error with this:

> > > import urllib2
> > >
> > > urllib2.urlopen('http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=ABT&a=11&b=27&c=2013&d=0&e=&(e)s&f=2013')

And the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused>

File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: urlopen error [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

If I put that url into a browser, it says cannot connect.  So it may not be a python issue.  I doubt the website has been down for as long as I've tried to make it work.  I've checked the proxies, and as far as I can tell, I'm not using a proxy.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Might be something on the router, since now using someone else's wifi network.  But what?

Comment: It works.  Must have been the website down.